# Options to protect contact form emails from being abused/spammed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spam-prevention

I will be offering a way for members of the public to email companies listed on my site (via a contact us form on their page) however, I want to put in place measures to prevent abuse (preferably not captcha).

Here's some of the options I have come up with - are there more, better ways to deal with it? (I am using Ruby on Rails 3)

- Create a table that records IP addresses, then place temporary bans (say 15 minutes) on IPs that have already sent X number of emails with say an hour. This should be able to deal with people and bot spamming from single IPs. Is it common for spammers to switch IPs? (I'd delete IPs that are over a week old, so the table should be fairly small at all times).
- Use a honeypot - hidden form field. This would help with bots only.
- Use the above two together
- Use captcha. Not really keen on this as people generally don't like it (and it's not a good option for APIs).

Are there more that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having timeouts on contact form submissions, associated by IP address is a good idea (always use the REMOTE_ADDR server environment variable, you cannot trust anything else. Also be prepared for IPv6 addresses).

The honeypot won't solve any problems and will just cause your site more traffic.

Captchas are useful - but you don't have to use typography / OCR captchas (like ReCAPTCHA). Simple generated mathematical expressions work fine too. I'd argue you do need a Captcha because contact forms are targeted by automated bots.

But the best spam protection is at the recipient's end. Failing that, use your own SMTP server that has its own content-based spam filter in place.